# Android 6 EditText.setError not working correctly

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-6.0-marshmallow, saripaar

I have upgraded to android 6 and seeing some strange things when trying to set validation for some editTexts.
I am using android-saripaar for validation:

```
@Email(messageResId = R.string.error_email)
private EditText email;
@Password(min = 6, scheme = Password.Scheme.ALPHA_NUMERIC_MIXED_CASE_SYMBOLS)
private EditText password;
@ConfirmPassword
private EditText repassword;
@NotEmpty(messageResId = R.string.error_name)
private EditText firstname;
@NotEmpty(messageResId = R.string.error_name)
private EditText lastname;
private Validator mValidator;
```

For some reason the email, password, confirm password are not showing the error message on the popup, while the last and first name are fine

[image]

I have tried without the library and the same issue occurred.
Using editText.setError("Some Message")
This did not happen prior to android 6 and was working fine on 5.

Anybody experienced similar to this? if so how did you fix it?

Comment: I haven't used that library, but it looks like a theme/style issue.

Comment: Try the validation without that library and see if it still doesn't work. I've seen this issue, but I think it was on Android 4.4 and 4.3 - never on Marshmallow or Lollipop.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue on android 5.1 and 6.0 and I'm not using any plugin for validation. This works fine on android 4.4 for me.

Comment: Hi, this issue isn't related to the library.

Answer (score 2):

use `getString(R.string.error_name)`

Comment: But the question shows `messageResId` - `getString(...)` will not return a resource identifier but the actual string, and it seems the library wants a resource identifier.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is related to activity theme, this what i'm using and working in android 6.0:

**activity theme :**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**code :** please note i'm extending `activity` not `AppCompatActivity`

```
myeditText.setError("Please enter valid email");
myeditText.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY `@NotEmpty` annotation on Email edittext field

```
@NotEmpty
@Email
private EditText email;
```