# Edittext setError does not show message in android 6.0

Tags: android, android-edittext

Edittext setError method is not showing text in android 6.0 but working perfectly in android 5.0. I have tried many solutions but don't get solution and i tried all solution of [Android 6 EditText.setError not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965466/android-6-edittext-seterror-not-working-correctly), So how to fix this issue?[image]

This is my xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_create_page"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivPageBanner"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_timeline"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivPageDp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/flagwithcamera" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etPageName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ivPageDp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Page name"
            style="@style/EditTextTheme"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/black_cursor"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_foreground_material_light" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is my style for Edittext:

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

and here is my Colors.xml:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#64100b</color>
<color name="transparent">#fc000000</color>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got my solution. Just removed this from my Edittext:

```
android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
```

Reason is underline below text of setError.

**Alright, but where are these underlines come from?**

`android:theme` is an attribute of View and when you set a style as `android:theme`, that style will be wrapped by ContextThemeWrapper with context theme while in inflation of view.

So that means, if you set `android:theme` property with style that contains `android:background` item like

```
<item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
```

every child view of this theme owner will be have a green background.

`"Widget.AppCompat.EditText"` is a style and references `?attr/editTextBackground` as a `"android:background"`. And in v21/values-21.xml file `@drawable/abc_edit_text_material` is defined as `editTextBackground`.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355788/5909385

Answer (score 1):

I think, It does showing but it is bit chopped off. Try using Floating Labels & Set Error to TextInputLayout reference. Please let me know if you still facing issue

Comment: TextInputLayout setError is working perfectly but I want edittext setError

Comment: May be your spinner widget overlapping error message there. Try to remove spinner layout temporary & try again.

Comment: Tried your solution but not getting perfect output.Situation is still same